# Persistent where clause SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add a persistent SQL where clause in SQLalchimy.
Basically I have a table containing a specific field, and I want all my request to add a where clause, so this field matches a clause.

For instance, if my request is

```
session.query( MyTable ).all()
```

I'd like the generated request to be as such :

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE specific_field = 'some_value';
```

Is there a way of doing this without adding a filter to each request ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885415/what-is-the-best-way-pre-filter-user-access-for-sqlalchemy-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add:

```
dbengine.echo = True
session.query(MyTable).filter_by(specified_field = 'some_value').all()
```

I'm not sure what you mean by: 'without adding a filter to each request.' My guess is that you don't want to filter the request client-side. The generated SQL for this should look a lot like what you're asking for; the `dbengine.echo = True` bit will show you the SQL that's generated.

**Update based on OP comment:**

If you really want all queries to have a filter, then a simple (but in my opinion not so pretty) way would be to add your own query method:

```
def myquery(self, table):
  self.query(table).filter_by(specified_field = 'some_value')

session.__class__.some_arbitrarily_filtered_query = myquery
```

After that, you can just call (for example):

```
session.some_arbitrarily_filtered_query(MyTable).all()
```

Comment: Yep but the aim would be to have the 

    filter_by(specified_field = 'some_value')

added automatically

Comment: I think I'm going to use the filter by hand, but thanks for the idea though !

Comment: @chouquette: That sounds like the right decision. If you use certain kinds of queries frequently, you can always put them in a function later -- I think that's one of the main benefits of using SQLAlchemy's query construction methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm *not* really suggesting this as it's overly complicated, but...

```
CREATE VIEW Table2 AS SELECT * FROM Table WHERE specific_field = 'some_value';
```

then you reflect the view with

```
table2 = sqlalchemy.Table('Table2', metadata, autoload=True)
```

and just query there, possibly mapping it (also providing the primary key) to

```
class MyTable2(MyTable):
    pass
```

untested, but should work